# How to find difference between two MySQL tables using MySQL statement?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables called MytableA and MytableB. MytableA holds 609 rows and MytableB holds 607 rows. Both Rows have same structure. I just want to find out what imageURL(s) exist in MytableA that don't exist in MytableB and display those missing rows? Could anyone tell me what is the MySQL statement to display those rows that are missing in MytableB?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `MytableA` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bio` varchar(90) DEFAULT NULL,
  `website` varchar(90) DEFAULT NULL,
  `profile` varchar(90) NOT NULL,
  `fullname` varchar(250) DEFAULT '',
  `diffId` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `imageUrl` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `PageURL` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `CreatedTime` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `imageTags` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist

Comment: show us what you tried so far

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM MyTableA
 WHERE imageURL NOT IN (SELECT imageURL FROM MyTableB)
```

There may be faster ways to do it, but this has the merit of succinctness.

Comment: Many Thanks it made job so easy :-)

Comment: for tables with more rows you would do a left join and test for null on the right side values

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this. It might be better and faster then subselect.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA 
LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.field = tableB.field 
WHERE tableB.field is NULL;
```