# remove duplicates between 2 tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
table1

   id     mcs     name     search_id
    1     14      name1    70
    2     14      name2    70
    3     14      name3    70

table2

  id    mcs     name     search_id
   1    14      name1    70
   2    14      name2    70
   3    14      name4    70
   4    14      name5    70
   5    14      name6    70
```

what i want is to select rows from table2 and not in table1 which has same mcs ans search_id .... my trying is

```
 create temporary table find_duplicates SELECT * FROM table2 T1 WHERE
            T1.mcs = T2.mcs AND T1.search_id = T2.search_id AND  T1.name IN ( SELECT T2.name FROM table2 T2) ;
```

but it gives me duplicate column named id ...
even when i tried this

```
     create temporary table find_duplicates SELECT )mcs,name,search_id) FROM table2 T1 WHERE
            T1.mcs = T2.mcs AND T1.search_id = T2.search_id AND  T1.name IN ( SELECT T2.name FROM table2 T2) ;
```

it gives me columns are ambiguous

any help ???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find difference between two MySQL tables using MySQL statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18964709/how-to-find-difference-between-two-mysql-tables-using-mysql-statement)

Comment: please read my question well

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
create table table1 (id  int,   mcs int  ,  name  varchar(10),     search_id int);
insert into table1 values
(    1,     14,      'name1',    70),
(    2,     14,      'name2',    70),
(    3,     14,      'name3',    70);

create table table2 (id  int,   mcs int  ,  name  varchar(10),     search_id int);
insert into table2 values
 (  1,    14,      'name1' ,   70),
 (  2,    14,      'name2' ,   70),
 (  3,    14,      'name4' ,   70),
 (  4,    14,      'name5' ,   70),
 (  5,    14,      'name6' ,   70);
 */

 create temporary table find_duplicates
 select t2.* 
 from   table2 t2
 left outer join        table1 t1 on t1.mcs = t2.mcs and t1.name = t2.name and t1.search_id = t2.search_id
 where  t1.id is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create temporary table find_duplicates
select distinct(t2.id) from table2 t2,table1 t1 where t1.mcs = t2.mcs 
and t1.search_id = t2.search_id and not find_in_set 
(t2.name,(select group_concat(name) from table1))
```

Comment: Adding some explanation would be great! :)

Comment: @gofr1 i dint get question batter . i just think that user want this result and i made this query. is it right or wrong ?

Comment: Sorry, I can not check it. Your answer was marked as low quality I guess due no explanation presents and I add comment about this matter :) If you have nothing to add - then OK. :)